the smallest volume of the cube that can contain 9 unit volume cubes
I have been thinking about this question for some time now. If the question was about 8 cubes, the answer is obvious as we can just fit them inside a cube of side $2cm$ and hence volume $8cm^3$.
However, how can we add another cube to this with minimal volume increase in the larger cube? I came up with an answer that is less than the obvious $27cm^3$. What I did was trying to reduce the problem to 2 dimensions and think of how large does a unit square has to be so that I can fit 5 unit squares in it. Well, I can put four squares in the corners of the larger square and I can fit a square in the middle with the vertices of those squares touching the middle of the side of the central square (I attached my drawing to represent it). 
This gives a side of the square measuring $(2 + \sqrt2/2)cm$ (simple calculation). This is less than the obvious answer of $3cm$. Now we can translate this idea to three dimensions and make a cube where we place one unit cube on each vertex of the large cube, and in the bottom (take 4 cubes touching the same face) we place a unit cube so that it touches the bottom face as well forming the solution I found for 2d. This gives us a solution of $(2 + \sqrt2/2)^3 cm^3$ which is less than the obvious $27cm^3$.
So here is the question: can I prove this solution is optimal? First, I did not find a way to prove that the 2d solution is optimal, even though intuitively it seems like it is. The total area of the square required for my solution is approximately $7.33$, so the "remaining" area not covered by squares (approximately $2.33$) gives "room" for another square to fit if there is an arrangement allowing it. Secondly, if I prove the solution in 2d is optimal, I could only say that the 3d "translation" of the 2d idea is also optimal if the projected vision in each face of the cube resulted in the optimal 2d solution. But such is not the case. But intuitively it seems to me that this is also the optimal solution for 3d. Is there a way to prove it?
Thanks in advance!

Your answer in the plane is provably correct. Wikipedia provides

The smallest value of $a$ that allows the packing of $n$
unit squares is known when $n$  is a
perfect square (in which case it is $\sqrt {n}$), as
well as for   $n$ = 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14, 15,
24, 34, 35, 46, 47, and 48.


Note that most of the values are missing in this list; $11$ is the first. In three dimensions the problem is even harder: Packing Cubes into a Cube Is NP-Hard in the Strong Sense.

Thanks! Do you have a free resource on the 3d case? I don’t have institutional access to the text you sent

You're welcome. I looked at the reference. It says nothing about exact answers for small numbers - it proves that there is no good algorithm to solve the general case. I found it searching google scholar for "pack cubes". I saw nothing about actual answers in three dimensions.
